# React/Redux: access props inside connect component

Tags: reactjs, redux

Usually my structure for a React/Redux component is like this:

```
 .Component
  ├── Component.less
  ├── ComponentConnect.js
  └── ComponentUi.js
```

A file for the style, a file for the connect, and another for the UI. Here is my connect component:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import actions from '../../redux/actions';
import selectors from '../../redux/selectors';
import ComponentUi from './ComponentUi';

export const ComponentConnect = connect(
    (state) => {

        return {
            friend: state.User ? state.User.friends.includes(this.props.id) : false,
        };
    },
    (dispatch) => {
        return {};
    }
)(ComponentUi);

export default ComponentConnect;
```

And this is my UI component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Component.less';

class ComponentUi extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="Component">
                My stuff here
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ComponentUi;
```

When I want to use the component I call the `ComponentConnect`, which receive props and pass it to `ComponentUi`. And as you can see, in `ComponentConnect` I am trying to filter the data returned by Redux, and I am trying to do it accessing `props`

```
state.User ? state.User.friends.includes(this.props.id) : false
```

Of course it returns an error, but I wonder if it is possible to access props in some way.

Answer (score 1):

The [`mapStateToProps` function](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments) is called with the `props` pass to the component as the 2nd param, so you can do this:

```
(state, props) => {
    return {
        friend: state.User ? state.User.friends.includes(props.id) : false,
    };
},
```